# Setting a static IP address.

Tags: 12.10, network-manager, ip, static-ip

I'm trying to set a static IP address in 12.10.

When I run `ifconfig`, I find that both lo and wlan0 have downloaded packets. In my /etc/network/interfaces file it says auto lo. Which should I be setting?

If I set the IP address the graphical way, through Network settings, do I need to change the settings for both IPV4 and IPV6?

How do I set my IP address to static and how do I know what ip address to use?

Comment: First: Why u need Static Ip?
Second: what is your gateway IP adress? If u run desktop edition, better do it graphical way. I need more details about your network confguration.. then i can point you to the right way..

Comment: I want it because I host a Minecraft server. What details do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a specific reason for wanting to set a static IP address? it's not needed in the vast majority of situations. If you do need it, it should be either by request from a network administrator at your organization (in which case it's his responsibility to assist you and provide the proper config values), or because you know you need it on a network you built.

> -First of all, when I run ifconfig, I find that both lo and wlan0 have downloaded packets. In my /etc/network/interfaces file it says auto
>   lo. Which should I be setting?

lo is an internal loopback interface. You don't need to change this one. Read about the loopback interface here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback

> -Secondly, every guide I've found does it as though eth0 is the main connection, but it isn't for me? So what should I be doing
>   differently?

What is your main connection? If it's eth1, you should apply the instructions from your guides to eth1 instead. Use common sense here :) It would help if you could tell us which guides you're looking at.

> -Next: If I do it the graphical way, through Network settings, do I need to change the settings for both IPV4 and IPV6? Every guide I've
>   found has only ever done it for IVP4.

Not unless you know you need IPV6. This would be something your network administrator can tell you. If it's your own network, *you* should know whether you have configured or need IPV6.

> -Lastly, how do I know what to set my ip address as when I set it to static?

Ah, here's the crux of the matter. You should *know* this, either because your network administrator told you "configure a static IP on your machine, here are the config parameters") or because you decided "I'll make my home network fully static, here's how I'm going to allocate my address space, here's the IP address for the gateway, this is the IP for my computer" and so on.

If you don't really know what IP address to set, then potentially you don't really need to set one.

I suggest you read up on what setting up a private network with static addresses entails (http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-a-Private-Network), you don't need to follow the instructions but it will help you understand how to plan a small network and determine whether you want/need to do this.

Comment: I want a static ip address because I host a Minecraft server, and it's getting rather tiresome texting my friends the ip address every time I put up the server. I was unsure of my main connection; but now that you've cleared up for me that it's not lo, then it must wlan0. Some of the guides I've been following are http://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu , http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-ubuntu-server-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address/ and http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=4053 Also, I am without a network admin because this is my home network.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How are you connecting to the internet? DSL? cable modem? You can configure your home router to forward minecraft connections to your computer regardless of its internal IP address, but in order to get a static "public" ip address (the one you give your friends) you would need to speak to your ISP. An easier route is to set up dynamic DNS, this way you give people a name like "schtocker-minecraft.dyndns.org" which doesn't change. Read here: http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Personal-Minecraft-Server

Comment: Okay, No-IP seems like my ideal solution. Problem is, and I'm not sure what I've done, but whenever the No-IP script is running I am unable to connect to the internet. I have to restart my laptop to be able to. When I ran `make install` I assumed it'd install it (I had to download the tar.gz) but it just took me to setup and then I couldn't connect to the internet.

Comment: Oh woops I forgot to tag @roadmr

Comment: Don't worry, I've now fixed it. I did as the No-IP website suggested and downloaded/installed it with wget. It now works perfeclty. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

#### static ip configuration example

Here is an example for a static configuration of interface eth0 in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
 iface eth0 inet static 
    address 10.1.2.3 
    netmask 255.255.240.0 
    broadcast 10.1.255.255
    dns-nameservers 10.1.2.3 10.1.2.3
    dns-search example.com
```

For more informations see [`man interfaces`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/interfaces.5.html)

Comment: `man interfaces` provides a very good reference on how to configure interfaces. It's a bit technical (not a tutorial!) but is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**How to set a static IP address in Ubuntu 12.10**

The best way to set a static IP address is through "DHCP reservation" on the router, not through the operating system because then you can leave your computer on "DHCP" so when you plug it in somewhere else, it just works.  I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and have a Cisco E2000 router to demonstrate.

1. Run `ifconfig` on the Ubuntu Box.

   ```
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:3d:7e:ea:9b:3a  
             inet addr:192.168.13.88  Bcast:192.168.13.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
             inet6 addr: fe80::d63d:7eff:feea:9b3a/64 Scope:Link
             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:1268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:872 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
             RX bytes:1114418 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:150044 (150.0 KB)
             Interrupt:20 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000
   ```

   That tells you the IP address is 192.168.13.88  I am connected with DHCP
2. Here my contents of /etc/network/interfaces, it is the default.  Don't touch this:

   ```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback
   ```
3. Log into your router.  Find the button called: "DHCP Reservation".

   If you can't find that button for your router, use the Google to type in "where is DHCP Reservation for my crunch-whirrr-bang router?"

   Click the "DHCP Reservation" button.  What that button means is you are telling the router to "remember the mac address of a computer, and when it requests an IP address, always give it THAT ip address, and give that IP address out to nobody else.

[image]

4. Check the checkbox in the upper right corresponding to the computer you want to set a static IP address.

[image]

5. Then click Add clients.
6. Click save settings.  Note this freezes the IP address to this computer as-is.  You may want to define your own, you need to know your computer's mac address and you can use the "Assign IP address" feature to link an IP address to the mac address of your computer.
7. Restart the computer, and the router will always give you that IP address.

Comment: I like this approach, and static dhcp leases are a great thing, but technically the IP is still dynamically assigned. if your router goes offline you cannot ping that pc. if you assign a static IP in the configuration, it will persist even if there is only that computer and a swith in play,

Answer (score 0):

If you come here looking for instructions for newer ubuntu versions, some of the commands refered to in these answers have become outdated.

- `ifconfig` has been replaced by `ip` run `ip addr` to see the ip addresses of your adapters
- `ethX` (where `X` is an integer) is no longer the default naming scheme.

Use `ip addr` to figure out your adapter name. from this example you can see that my adapter is called `eno1`

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6Ø:1Å:PD:2M:9Y:X9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0
    inet 10.11.12.13/24 brd 10.11.12.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fGG0::6YYd:eXXX:XeXX:94ÅÅ/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## Editing the configuration

Some guides will say edit `/etc/network/interfaces` some will say use `NetworkManager` those are all outdated. You may experience upgraded servers that still use those old config files, but on a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 the config is in `/etc/netplan/`

In my case this is called `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` since the config I had originally was made by Ubuntu's [Ubiquity](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ubiquity.8.html) installer.

### /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
       addresses:
         - 10.11.12.13/24
       nameservers:
         addresses: [4.2.2.2, 8.8.8.8]
       routes:
         - to: default
           via: 10.11.12.1
  version: 2
```

This is my config using the subnet `10.11.12.0/24` with a default gateway with IP  `10.11.12.1` set up to use a [level 3 dns (4.2.2.2)](https://serverfault.com/questions/88115/who-does-the-nameserver-4-2-2-2-belong-to) and Google's dns server (`8.8.8.8`).
Some  guides say to use `gateway4: 10.11.12.1` instead of the `routes:` entry in my example. gateway4 is deprecated in Ubuntu 22.04

### Applying the configuration

In order to apply the config execute `sudo netplan apply` if you sense that something is not working use `sudo netplan --debug apply` see the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/netplan.8.html) for more details.

## Troubleshooting

- **My adapter is still down according to `ip addr` after doing `netplan apply`** Check if the adapter name in the configuration is the same as the one in `ip`
- **I can't ping the internet** ensure that you have entered everything as in my example. The format is a YAML array, and yaml files are normally indented with two spaces. Also ensure that you have written the correct gateway address (it may be 192.168.1.234 for example)