# How to set permanent ip address from script

Tags: networking

Like this post [states](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264408/setting-a-static-ip-address) I can edit the file to have some Ip address configuration.
Is it possible to have some command line utility.  which does it for me? like:

```
   sudo configutilcommand -mode static -ip 192.168.7.2 -mask 255.255.255.0 .....
```

or something like this, so I wont need it to edit file.

p.s. configutilcommand is a hypothetical my invented stuff for example purpose.

Comment: Which Ubuntu? `nmcli` could probably do what you need if you are using NetworkManager: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/nmcli.1.html

Answer (score 0):

For setting a ip address on interface you can use fallowing command

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

after that

```
sudo route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

And you network will work.

If you wish put this command in `/etc/rc.local`

Use `eth0` if you configure wired connection if you try to add ip on wless conection use `wlan0`.
List of interfaces you will get with command `ifconfig`