# Trouble setting static IP address in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, static-ip, hyper-v

I will preface all of this by saying I'm a Linux noob, but have years supporting Windows Server environments, going back to WinNT 4 beta, in a commercial environment. While I have played around with a few Linux desktop setups, this is my first run at a server setup. The system is virtual, running under Hyper-V on my Win10 Pro desktop for now. Once running fine, I have a Win2016 Hyper-V Server, on an HP server, that I will be transferring this to.

First installed server using DHCP, but as I plan to use it as a Samba DC, DNS, and DHCP server, I want to go to a static address. Using the GUI, I went into Network and it showed the dynamic IP of the system. With Wired highlighted, I clicked on the Options button. In there, `eth0` did not appear. I made a new connection, `eth1`.

There I set Ethernet connection 1, IPv4 Settings, changed the Method from DHCP to Manual and entered the static IP address information. Closed that by clicking on the Save button. Rebooted the system and Network still reports `eth0` DHCP IPv4 address, with the `eth1` info appearing only after clicking on the Options button.

Going into Terminal, I run `ifconfig` and it only shows `eth0` with the DHCP address, nothing about `eth1`.

I have used `nano` to manually set the ip info for `eth0`, using instructions found on this site to make sure I didn't overlook something. When I do that and reboot, `eth0` disappears entirely. `ifconfig` will then only report the `lo` interface.

To say I'm frustrated would be an understatement. Just in case, I went into the virtual machine settings, under Network Adapter, Advanced Features, and gave the virtual NIC a static MAC address (default is Dynamic). Unfortuanately, that has not seemed to fix the issue.

So how do I set a static IP address?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"eth0 disappears entirely"*? if you mean that it no longer appears in the NetworkManager GUI, then that's normal -  once you configure an interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`, NetworkManager relinquishes control of it by default (`managed=false` for the `[ifupdown]` plugin)

Comment: Have a look at this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/264408/setting-a-static-ip-address?rq=1

Comment: When I run ifconfig prior to manual configuration, it shows eth0 and lo. After manually setting the eth0 info, ifconfig only shows lo. eth0 has disappeared. I was not talking about NetworkManager at that point.  Also, prior to doing the manual config, I tried using NetworkManager to set it to static. When I first opened NetworkManager, it showed eth0's info fine. I clicked the Options button to change it to static, but when I did, NM reported no wired connections available and only offered the option to create a new connection. Interestingly, it started numbering at 1, not 0, so 0 was in use.

Comment: Finally got an answer to the problem. Turns out what I thought was a line-wrap at the beginning of the file was not. As a result, the /etc/network/interfaces file was not being parsed, as there was garbage in the file that was supposed to be comments. The missing # caused the system to dump processing of the file, causing it to not be able to bring up the interface.