# Port forwarding Linux->Windows

Tags: wireless, ethernet, network-bridge, rdp

My situation is the following: I have an old laptop with Wi-Fi and Ethernet onboard, windows PC with no Wi-Fi and my new laptop with both. I want to have remote desktop access from my new laptop to PC wirelessly via my old laptop. To do this I've bind old laptop and PC with ethernet cable and enabled Internet Sharing on the laptop, with this TeamViewer works perfectly, however, as mostly I am working from home, I've been thinking about setting up RDP over the local network. To do this, as far as I understand I need some kind of port-forwarding or ip binding, can anyone help?
Linux Lubuntu, Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remote desktop from Windows to Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280220/remote-desktop-from-windows-to-lubuntu)

Comment: Since both machine are on the same local network, *port forwarding* is NOT needed. Simply change your router settings to assign the old laptop a consistent IP address.

Comment: @user535733, and what ip should I provide RDP app with?

Comment: That's why you assign the old laptop a consistent IP address.

Comment: The problem is that while my desktop Win PC is connected to Wi-Fi via old laptop it doesn't show up in the local network, only old laptop ip is visible, and I was thinking is there any way to pass 3389 port from my PC to the local network to make It possible for RDP apps to connect from different devices all over the local network

Comment: It is already static..

Comment: Port Forwarding is done across a router. Your network is already on one side of the router, so Port Forwarding won't do anything. If devices on your local network cannot see your old laptop, then you chose a poor IP address. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/264408/setting-a-static-ip-address for ways to fix it.